# How to append attributes of a model to an object

Tags: laravel, object, model, attributes

In Laravel, I have model `City`, with attributes `name`, `lat`, `long`, when I print the city it outputs as:

```
        {
            "name": "San Juan",
            "latitude": 66.66,
            "longitude": 44.44
        }
```

However I need this to always print out in the following format, with the`lat` and `long` in a `geolocation` object.

```
        {
            "name": "San Juan",
            "geolocation": {
                "latitude": 66.66,
                "longitude": 44.44
            }
        }
```

can this be done in my `City.php` model class?

Comment: The option is to `json_decode()` the json object to array and add required fields.Then `json_encode` to get json object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will remove lat and long attributes and replace them with new attribute
geolocation and its type will be json in format {"latitude": 66.66,"longitude": 44.44}.

Comment: How this become the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$z= json_decode($y);
$z->geolocation = ['latitude' => $z->latitude,'longitude' => $z->longitude];
unset($z->latitude);
unset($z->longitude);
echo json_encode($z);
```

Output will be

```
{
  "name":"San Juan",
  "geolocation":
   {
     "latitude":66.66,
     "longitude":44.44

   }
}
```